# pdftk can't handle emdashes in filenames

Tags: ubuntu, filenames, unicode, pdftk

I'm trying to use pdftk (v 1.40) to combine some pdfs (using it's `cat` command).  As a simple test, I can do

```
pdftk "/home/deploy/Foo - Bar.pdf" cat output results.pdf
```

and that works fine (I'm only combining one file here, but it's still a valid test).  But, if the filename has an emdash it balks:

```
$ pdftk "/home/deploy/Foo — Bar.pdf" cat output results.pdf
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   /home/deploy/Foo — Bar.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

The file exists:

```
$ ls -l ~/Foo*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 deploy deploy 15180 2017-11-01 11:15 /home/deploy/Foo - Bar.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 deploy deploy 15180 2017-11-01 11:14 /home/deploy/Foo — Bar.pdf
```

I googled this a bit and saw [someone](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=258377) complaining that it can't handle umlauted characters, so I thought it might be something to do with extended character sets, or character encoding generally.

Comment: The solution was just to upgrade pdftk, doh.  I don't know whether to delete this question or put an answer in for it....

Comment: Posting an answer would be great!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters this, the solution was simply to upgrade pdftk.  I had version 1.40, the fix was in v1.41!